# Group observations in ggplot2 with long form data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data in long form that looks like this:

```
id <- rep(seq(1:16), each = 3)
trial <- rep(seq(1:3), times = 16)
repeatedMeasure <- round(rnorm(48, mean = 3, sd = 2))
measuredOnce <- rep(10:14, times = c(9,6,6,12,15))
con1 <- rep(c('hi', 'lo'), each = 6, times = 4)
con2 <- rep(c('up', 'down'), each = 3, times = 8)

dat <- as.data.frame(cbind(id, trial, con1, con2, repeatedMeasure, measuredOnce))

dat$measuredOnce <- as.character(dat$measuredOnce)
dat$measuredOnce <- as.numeric(dat$measuredOnce)
```

Participants complete multiple trials. There is a unique measurement for each trial in the 'repeatedMeasures' variable. However, they are only measured once for the variable titled 'measuredOnce'. I want to produce a bar plot of the measuredOnce variable - something like this:

```
ggplot(data = dat) +
  aes(x = measuredOnce) +
  geom_bar() +
  facet_wrap(~con1*con2)
```

However, I want to specify that the measurements for measuredOnce are grouped by id, so that the number of observations (and hence the height of the bar) is divided by three.

I know I could produce what I want by using spread() or taking every third row, but would like to work with the same (long) data frame.

Edit: plot using code above with group = id and fill = id added to aesthetics.

[image]

Edit 2: What I am looking for is something that looks like the plot produced by this code

```
dat %>% 
  spread(key = trial, value = repeatedMeasure) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = measuredOnce) +
  geom_bar() +
  facet_wrap(~con1*con2)
```

but without creating a new data frame using spread().

Comment: add `, group = id, fill = id` in `aes`

Comment: Hi @Mateusz1981, thanks for the suggestion. I had tried group = id but not in combination with fill = id. However, this doesn't fix the issue - as you can see in the screen shot, the bar heights are still incorrect. I also don't want individual fills for each participant or a legend though I could fix that I assume.

Comment: Hi, you'd like something like this `ggplot(data = dat) +aes(x = measuredOnce, group = trial, fill = trial) +geom_bar() +facet_wrap(~con1*con2) `?

Comment: Hi @nhl. No, that gives more or less the same outcome as the previous comment. What I want is something that looks like this:

`dat %>% 
  spread(key = trial, value = repeatedMeasure) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = measuredOnce) +
  geom_bar() +
  facet_wrap(~con1*con2)`

but without having to create a new dataframe using spread().
Question has been edited to clarify.

Comment: This? `dat %>% 
  select(measuredOnce, id, con1, con2) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = measuredOnce, fill=id)) +
  geom_bar() +
  facet_grid(con1~con2)`

Comment: Hi @Jimbou, Yes, that gives more or less the result I am after, but it is the same type of solution as the one I've added in Edit 2 above - the data frame is transformed before the plot is created. I am wondering whether it is possible to get that plot while still working with the long form data frame with all rows. It is mostly a matter of curiosity, because there are clearly solutions (like yours) that are easy to implement. The reason for my question is my understanding of ggplot was that it was designed to work with long form data, so I was surprised that transformation was needed.